# Ajax call returning a Uncaught TypeError when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

I have a rails project where I'm making a couple of get requests through AJAX. When I run it locally, the request comes back to me and I'm able to parse through the data and append it to my view page. However, when I pushed up to Heroku, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stops' of null
```

The line the error is referencing is from my first AJAX call. When I run locally it returns data back to me (no errors at all when I have the console open and view it), so not sure why it wouldn't work once deployed. My guess would be that it's assuming that the value for 'stops' has finished (which it seems to be locally), but on Heroku it's using it before its returned. I'm not sure why. Hoping that someone might have an idea as to why this is happening.

I do know that my view is recognizing my javascript page - threw an alert message just to make sure it was firing and it worked. Just not everything else that involves the AJAX calls (although it might just be this first AJAX call that's causing the issue).

Below if my AJAX request if that helps:

```
// some code above
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: response,
  data: {},
  success: function(result){    
    var stopObjects = Array.prototype.slice.call(result.data.stops);
    requestStopData(stopObjects);
  }
});
// some code below
```

Thanks, appreciate any and all suggestions.

**EDIT:** I thought I should also mention that part of the get request's URL requires latitude and longitude coordinates from using HTML's geolocation (not sure if that would cause the issue, but wanted to mention it). Thanks.

Comment: The error message means: within your `success` handler, `result.data` is `null`, and so `result.data.stops` doesn't exist. The first thing to do is inspect the network request and response of the Ajax call, which may contain useful details for debugging this issue. Use your browser's developer tools ([Chrome's DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-resource-details), [Firefox's Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Network_request_details), etc) and inspect the HTTP headers and response body of the Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Did check it out and the headers seem fine. I'm now wondering if it's an issue with dotenv as I'm using it to hide API keys and the url of the request depends on those keys as part of the address. Will see if that's the issue. Appreciate the help. Thanks!